# How can I restore Notepad after having it infected by a virus?

Tags: notepad, virus-removal

My computer got attacked by a Notepad.exe virus on Windows 7.

I've gotten rid of it, but now the standard Notepad program is missing. I can't run any of my .txt files.

What should I do to repair this?

Comment: use a notepad replacement such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: Remove the infection with [SuperAntiSpyware](http://www.superantispyware.com) and [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php)

Step 2: Run `sfc /scannow` to repair your system files

Step 3: Install a good antivirus

Step 4: Run all Windows Updates

Step 5: (Optional) Get a different text editor, like [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com)

Answer (score 5):

It is likely that Notepad has just not been reset as your default text editor. You will need to change the file association back to enable it.

To change file type and program associations: Source with pictures [Here](http://www.askdrtech.com/solutions/post/Setting-File-Associations-In-Windows-7.aspx)

1. Go to [Start], then press [Default Programs] button:
2. In the opened window, select [Associate a file type or protocol with a program] link:
3. It may take some time while the system is scanning PC for all available file types and programs:
4. After scan has been performed, the list of all supported, available file types and programs will be shown up:
5. Select a file type you need to associate with the another program (for example, .GIF) and press [Change Program] button to change the default program:
6. A new window with the available programs appeares, choose that on which is most suitable:
7. Set default program for opening file and press OK. In the list of file types and programs now one can see changed program association:

Answer (score 0):

Remove virus. After that, try to delete c:\windows\notepad.exe. The SO must recover the original file after some time.